# Nonbreaking colon in Android

Tags: android, scala, line-breaks

I have the following line of text: `address:345346943693495349534963`
I want this line to always break like this (exact breaking point is not important but it should not be a colon):

```
address:3453469436934
95349534963
```

On my Android 4.2.2 device it breaks as above, but on Android 6.0 emulator it behaves differently:

```
address:
345346943693495349534963
```

How do I make a breaking behavior consistent across all devices?

I get different results when I draw a text on canvas, here's the code (in Scala):

```
def paint = {
    val newPaint = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    newPaint setTextSize getResources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.text_size)
    newPaint setTypeface Typeface.create("Droid Sans", Typeface.NORMAL)
    newPaint setTextAlign Paint.Align.CENTER
    newPaint setStyle Paint.Style.FILL
    newPaint setColor Color.BLACK
    newPaint
}

def drawText(canvas: Canvas, text: String, x: Float, baseY: Float) = {
    val layout = new StaticLayout(text, paint, textBounds, ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f, false)
    val y = baseY - layout.getHeight / 2f

    canvas.save
    canvas.translate(x, y)
    layout draw canvas
    canvas.restore
}

drawText(canvas, gText, bitmap.getWidth / 2, topSize / 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for the Word Joiner unicode codepoint
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_joiner

It's also know as Zero Width no-break space (ZWNBSP).

According to this other question:
[Zero-width line breaking space for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594979/zero-width-line-breaking-space-for-android)

it should be supported on Android since version 5 (Lollipop). The same goes for soft-hypen (suggested in PhilLab response).

I would suggest you to try it out, you can write it as `&#8203;` in the XML resource string. Put it between the colon and the number.

If it doesn't work before Lollipop and you need support for previous platform the only other thing I can think about is measuring the text, character by character and, knowing the available width of your view (which you have to compute separately), manually add a new line in the text where you want it to split.

You can see how the Text measurement works in Android by reading this article:
https://chris.banes.me/2014/03/27/measuring-text/

Maybe there's a way to do it using Spans too, but I'm not aware of any.

Comment: thanks for accepting the answer, which solution did you go for?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [soft hypens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen) (\u00AD) which you have to place at several points in your number string:

```
address:3\u00AD453469\u00AD4369\u00AD349534953\u00AD4963
```

Unfortunately, this will render the hyphens, I don't know if that is okay for you:

```
address:3453469436934-
95349534963
```

This also works with the `android:text` attribute of TextViews.

P.S:
I also thought about using Html like this:

```
Html.fromHtml("<span style="display: inline-block;">address:3</span>45346943693495349534963");
```

but unfortunately I could not make it work in Android

Answer (score 0):

```
    before draw a text on canvas follow following step and 

               String temp = "address:345346943693495349534963";
               String firstString=temp.substring(0, 21);
               [![enter image description here][1]][1]String secondString = temp.substring(20);
               String finalString = firstString+"\n"+secondString;

    now finally draw a text on canvas with "finalString",and if set text in textview then set final string in textview.

               TextView yourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
               yourTextView.setText(finalString);


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/godJJ.png
```